# GetStream.io Chat API - Stop Listening for channel Events in Stream

Tags: javascript, angular, getstream-io

I'm confused by the documentation on how to stop listening for channel events in JS using the Stream Chat API. 
[As per the docs:](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/event_listening/?language=js)

```
// remove the handler for all "message.new" events on the channel
channel.off("message.new", myChannelEventHandler);
```

What is `myChannelEventHandler`?

My `channel.on` looks like this, from the example Angular application:

```
this.channel.on('message.new', event => {
    this.messages = [...this.messages, event.message];
});
```

This is the only time `myChannelEventHandler` ever referenced in the docs, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It's your `event => {}` that you are providing.  It's the callback.  To be able to remove that specific handler, you will need to store it off in a variable, that can be used in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586174/taplar), I've gotten this working. Solution is as simple as this:

Define a message event handler, and create a property for the Angular component class:

```
messageEventHandler = event => {
    this.messages = [...this.messages, event.message];
};
```

Use event handler for channel on:

```
this.channel.on('message.new', this.messageEventHandler)
```

Use the same event handler for channel off:

```
this.channel.off('message.new', this.messageEventHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest refactoring the code so you can reference your function inside `channel.off`. This is more a JavaScript language question

```
const myChannelEventHandler = event => {
    this.messages = [...this.messages, event.message];
}

this.channel.on('message.new', myChannelEventHandler);

// remove the handler for all "message.new" events on the channel
// Apply this whenever you need
channel.off("message.new", myChannelEventHandler);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer was unclear. I did refactor so that I can reference my function from inside `channel.off`. The first code block is an Angular class property which are declared without `const` or `let`.